# $V$ and $V^B$ when $B$ is atomic

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

Let $B$ be a complete Boolean algebra in $V$ and $V^B$ be the Boolean-valued universe defined in the standard way. For any $x \in V$, $\check{x}$ is defined as $\{ \langle \check{y}, 1_B \rangle\ : y \in x \}$. When $B$ is atomic, is there a direct way of proving that for every formula $\varphi$, $V \models \varphi(x)$ iff $V^B \models \varphi(\check{x})$ (i.e., the $B$ value of $\varphi(\check{x})$ is $1_B$)?

I know that if we start with a transitive model $M$ of ZFC and consider an atomic complete Boolean algebra $B$ in $M$, then using Boolean-ultrapower we can show that $M$ is an elementary submodel of $M^B$ in the sense above. But I wonder if there is a proof of this fact about $V$ and $V^B$ without going through any transitive model.

Comment: If the complete Boolean algebra $B$ is atomic, then the Boolean truth value of the statement "all sets are in the ground model" is $1$. (In general, the truth value of that statement is the supremum of the atoms of $B$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Could you please elaborate on that? I guess you mean that for any $u \in V^B$, $\bigvee_{x \in V} [u = \check{x}]^{V^B} = 1$. How does that gives us the result?

Comment: For any formula $\phi(x)$, let $\phi'(\check x)$ be the formula obtained from $\phi(x)$ by (1) replacing the free variable $x$ with $\check x$ and (2) restricting all quantified variables $y$ to satisfy $\\bigvee_{a\in V}[y=\check a]$. Then check, by induction on formulas $\phi$, that the $V^B$-truth-value $[\phi'(\check x)]$ is 1 or 0 according to whether $\phi(x)$ is true or false (in $V$).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you!!! I see now.